# Credentials based on environment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

As per this: https://medium.com/cedarcode/rails-5-2-credentials-9b3324851336

It says that i can set up my credentials based on the environment I am in

I did this in credentials:

```
development:
  aws:
    access_key_id: xxxxx
    secret_access_key: xxxx
    region: antarctica-zim-123
    s3_bucket_name: xx

  stripe:
    publishable_key: pk_test_xxxx
    secret_key: sk_test_Jqxxxx

  paypal:
    client_id: xxxx
    client_secret: xxx
```

Then i attempted both ways to access:

```
Rails.application.credentials[Rails.env.to_sym][:stripe][:publishable_key]
Rails.application.credentials[Rails.env.to_sym].dig(:stripe, :publishable_key)
```

Neither worked.

Is there a way to do this?

Or is credentials production only, or really just you're only able to pass through what you want to use at the time?

Answer (score 0):

One way I found was simply:

```
Rails.application.credentials.send(Rails.env)[:key]
```